# check a list of values is in another nested list python and returns match

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, nested-lists

I have two lists of values

```
lst_a = [701221,310522,5272,8868,1168478,874766]
nested_lst_b = [[701221,310522,765272,12343],[8868,1168478,98023],[83645,5272],[63572,88765,22786]]
```

I want to check if every value in `lst_a`  is in `nested_lst_b` and return the matched values

Expected outputs:

```
output = [[701221,310522],[8868,1168478],[5272],[]]
```

I wrote the coding below but it didn't get what I expected...

```
for x,y in zip(lst_a,nested_lst_b):
    if x in y:
        print(x,y)

>>>701221 [701221, 310522, 765272, 12343]
>>>5272 [83645, 5272]
```

Can anyone help me with the problem? Thanks so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one, simple way to do it based on your initial attempts:

```
lst_a = [701221,310522,5272,8868,1168478,874766]
nested_lst_b = [[701221,310522,765272,12343],[8868,1168478,98023],[83645,5272],[63572,88765,22786]]

a_in_b = []
for sub_lst_b in nested_lst_b:
    a_in_sub = []
    for el_a in lst_a:
        if el_a in sub_lst_b:
            a_in_sub.append(el_a)
    a_in_b.append(a_in_sub)

print(a_in_b)
```

Here you loop through every sublist of `nested_lst_b` and check if any element in `lst_a` is in that sublist. It follows your output requirements (nested list corresponding to `nested_lst_b`.

Otherwise, this type of problem may for instance be solved using sets.

Comment: Gladly! Careful with zip btw., I thought it throws if the lists aren't the same length, but no, it will just iterate until the end of the shortest.

Answer (score 2):

One other solution would be using `set.intersection`, but it requires some casting between datatypes.

```
print([list(set.intersection(set(lst_a), set(b))) for b in nested_lst_b])

[[310522, 701221], [8868, 1168478], [5272], []]
```